# Alternative of iframe, Embed, Object tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I need to load external URL content in my php page. 
I have already used the above code but I don't want to use these tags due to some reasons.

```
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/"  height="200" width="300"></iframe>
<embed src="https://stackoverflow.com/" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:none;" />
<object data="https://stackoverflow.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

I need to load the content and if i click on any link of that loaded content it should load on the **same page** rather than redirecting.

Comment: Search for SPA (SinglePageApplication).

Comment: Why you don't use `ajax` to load content? (you can get it as string and do what ever you like)

Comment: I can use ajax to load content but after loading the content, if i click on any link in that content, it will redirect, which i don't want. I want to remain on the same page.

Comment: That's what links do, they redirect. You've to capture every link, and do an AJAX call instead of the default action. When you create a SPA, it's something you've to consider from the very beginning when planning your site/pages, there's a lot of stuff which has to be implemented differently from more traditional pages.